# What is the use of the third argument name in the url()? Why is there a comma in the urlpatterns list eventough there is only one element?

Tags: python, django, url

I am doing a django project(tutorial) and I came across this code in the urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I used this file and got the correct output. But, again, for experimenting, i omitted the "name" parameter from the url function. There was only two arguments, the regex and the view. Like this:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index),
 ]
```

And still, I got the correct output. 
So, why is there a third argument, the name parameter in the url function?

Also, the urlpatterns list contains only 1 element and yet we are using a ","(comma) before closing the list. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is there a third argument, the name parameter in the url function?

The `name` of a URL is so you can *reverse* it, i.e. get a URL for a particular view. You might use this when generating internal links, for example.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls):

> A common need when working on a Django project is the possibility to obtain URLs in their final forms either for embedding in generated content (views and assets URLs, URLs shown to the user, etc.) or for handling of the navigation flow on the server side (redirections, etc.)
>
> …
>
> The primary piece of information we have available to get a URL is an identification (e.g. the name) of the view in charge of handling it. Other pieces of information that necessarily must participate in the lookup of the right URL are the types (positional, keyword) and values of the view arguments.

Let's consider an example:

Imagine you're building a website, and you want to make an "about us" page. You're also really into dinosaurs, so you think to yourself, "wouldn't it be cool if my URLs were all dinosaur names?" So you put something like this into `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^tyrannosaurus-rex$', views.about_us),
```

Now you want to link to that page, maybe in your navigation bar. No problem. you put something like this in your template:

```html
<a href="/tyrannosaurus-rex">About Us</a>
```

This works, but you've duplicated some information: that your "about us" page can be found at `/tyrannosaurus-rex`.

For some reason you're getting very little traffic to your site, so you hire somebody to look at your search engine optimization. They tell you that your URLs should really have something to do with the content on the page instead of being cool dinosaur names. Here, your "about us" page should be at something like `/about-us`. Now you have to go back and update code in *two* places: `urls.py` and your template. Now imagine doing that for every link you have.

Instead, if you put

```
url(r'^tyrannosaurus-rex$', views.about_us, name='about_us'),
```

into `urls.py` you can link to it using [the `url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) like this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'about_us' %}">About Us</a>
```

Django will look at the name of the URL you want and use the information in `urls.py` to figure out what the link should point to. Now when you change your link structure you only need to do it once: in `urls.py`. Because the *name* of the link doesn't change, `{% url 'about_us' %}` automatically generates a new, proper link.

> Also, the urlpatterns list contains only 1 element and yet we are using a ","(comma) before closing the list. Why is that?

The list includes a comma even though there is only one element because it's slightly easier. Python permits the comma, and now we can easily add entries before or after this one without having to change it.

Comment: I didn't  really get the concept of reversing url. Could you please elaborate it? Thanks.

Comment: @polarG7, I've added an example.